# What is the process for turning light energy into heat?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

I am thinking about the following situation where I am in a room with no windows and I turn the light off. Since the room immediately goes dark, I guess the photons emmitted by the bulb are somehow absorbed by the walls, and converted into heat or longer wavelengths of light.

My question is, what physical theory models this interaction? Basic quantum mechanics says that photons can be absorbed by an atom to excite an electron, but then this same model would then say that the atom would eventually reemit a photon of the same wavelength. So according to this wouldn't the photons from the bulb would keep bouning around the room perpetually? What is the theory that tells us how the photons energy is converted into other forms?

Comment: You might be looking for "absorption spectroscopy" but I'm not sure. I have a feeling you want the deep extended explanation rather than the standard "it's absorbed and turned into heat" one. I'm curious of the FULL answer myself.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a single-atom system then the electron will inevitably return to a lower energy state and emit a photon. But in crystals there are more complicated relaxation mechanisms such as [recombination processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier_generation_and_recombination) and the generation of [polarons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polaron) (whereby  energy is transferred to the nuclei/phonons).

Answer (score 0):

I recently mentioned this question to a friend who offered this, which I think is quite a simple viewpoint, so thought I would share it and answer my own question:

Viewing light in the classical theory of electromagnetism, and matter has its own electromagnetic field through which a light wave can propagate. The mattter of the walls is much more densely populated by atoms that the air in the room, which may be approximated as a vaccuum. Thus the oscillations of the (approximate) vaccuum in the room are just transferred over to osscillations of the fields generated by all the constituent electrons and protons in the walls. This in turn makes those atoms jiggle about, and kinetic energy (heat) is imparted to the walls, serving to damp the electromagnetic wave.

Maybe this model is flawed (in which case please offer comments), and maybe it was too simple for people to consider mentioning, but it satisfied me quite well. I'll leave the question open anyway in case anyone wants to comment or offer any other models :)